# What's a good way to batch check media files for integrity?

Tags: windows, batch, media, data-integrity

I have some 15000 image, video and audio files (and also a few others) that I have been bouncing back and forth via FTP from my phone. After so many times, I found out that a few of them were corrupted. This is no big deal, as all of the media is backed up either on Google Photos or in some other way.

The problem is that the sets of files (local and backup) aren't the same and it would be very troublesome to try and compare checksums. What seems to be the best approach is running some scanner to find this handful of broken files and than manually download their copies.

I did search around quite a bit, but couldn't really find an adequate tool. My closest try was [this python script](https://github.com/ftarlao/check-media-integrity) on Github, but I never got it to work, seems to be above me.

BTW, I'm on Windows 10.

Any suggestions are much appreciated

Thank you

Comment: You've said nothing about preventing / verifying  the corruption during FTP.  Why are you trying to fix the problem after the fact when you should be concentrating on preventing / verifying problem during FTP?

Comment: I already know how to do that and have already prepared ways to verify checksum on future runs, but I didn't know that I had to do it until I was casually scrolling through a folder and found a couple broken files... which I already had mirrored over (between phone and PC) by then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved every hiccup on what I had, here's what did the trick:

For [check-media-integrity](https://github.com/ftarlao/check-media-integrity), I had to:

1. Use [this fork](https://github.com/garygan89/check-media-integrity) from garygan89;
2. Have all the required modules on both Python 2 and 3, as the original is supposed to be written for 2 and the fork, to have a conversion to 3, so instead of figure every issue out, I just had the requirements on both;
3. Use [these Python Wheels](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pillow-simd) to install Pillow-SIMD. This was the biggest issue to be solved, as compiling it from the source on Windows is at least very troublesome;
4. Install the ffmpeg-python module as a requirement. It's not listed on the project's readme.md, but it is listed on a separate requirements file;
5. For ffmpeg stuff, specify all the switches to broaden it's output;
6. Experiment a lot with optional values on timeout and threads. My optimal seemed to be around 75 threads and a timeout of at least 120 (400 when dealing with big files);
7. Use [WizTree](https://antibody-software.com/web/software/software/wiztree-finds-the-files-and-folders-using-the-most-disk-space-on-your-hard-drive/) and robocopy to apply the tool to smaller groups of files, the tools help on knowing what file extensions are in your folders and then on moving it to a "passed" folder.

For PDFs, I didn't get the desired from check-media-integrity, so I used [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), which can load/read a few dozen files at a time and will display an error message, if broken.

There were also a few files with no extension, which I simply opened on Notepad++ and tried to guess from whatever headers were there plus file size. Found some .mp4, .pdf, .pgn, .png. .jpeg and .apk files, which almost all worked fine after properly renamed.

Using all of this, I was able to parse my fileset (which I guess I increased in the meanwhile to 25 000) and find some 50 corrupt files and then replace'em as I wanted.